# How to execute two different client side functions with button click?

Tags: asp.net

Is it possible to execute two or more client side functions with a single button click? (I have written 3 functions in my .aspx page and need to validate on client side)

If yes please send me sample code with 3 client side functions using single button click.

Regards,

NSJ

Answer (score 1):

Of course it's possible:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" Id="myButton" onClientClick="function1(); function2(); function3();" />
```